# Creating separate log files for CronTrigger jobs in java

Tags: java, log4j, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

Need to create separate log files, one for each job triggered via CronTrigger (in Quartz scheduler). Name of the log files to be as per the job name. Is it possible?